# Protect file from direct access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a folder in which I save files. These files can be accessed from the web page. Let's say that the directory is like `manual/fileName.pdf`.

I also have a page to show a listing of stored files in the `manual/` folder and this page is protected using user sessions. So you have to login first before accessing the page.

I read that by placing a `.htaccess` in the folder, I can prevent users from accessing the files directly. But now I can't access them even from that listing page.

Here what I write in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .documentation.php
```

And here's my file listing script:

```
if ($handle = opendir('manual')) {
   while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
     if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
        if (!preg_match('/.php/', $entry) && !preg_match('/.htaccess/', $entry)) //prevent some file to be shown
            {echo "<a href='manual/$entry' target='_blank'>$entry</a><hr>";}
         }
     }
     closedir($handle);
}
```

Any idea how to access the files?

Comment: And the php listing works if you drop the htaccess? I don't think so.

Comment: Yes. Why did you think that?

Comment: Because `opendir` opens the directory even though the webserver throws a 500  internal error. Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: What i mean here is, the list appear & shown the list. But as i make them as a link too, the link don't open the file (it should be open the file if you click the link)

Answer (score 4):

Generally, it's not a good idea to serve protected files from within the document root. Specially, when users need to login to see/access them. When you delegate the serving to the webserver, you loose the ability to programmatically check if the user is logged in, since there's no way for the Apache web server to know if a user is authenticated within your PHP application. Once a user knows about the file URL, she can access the file without being logged in to the system.

There's a workaround which I'll get you through. But I strongly suggest you to place the files outside of your webroot and develop a script to deliver them when accessed. This way you can check for an authenticated and authorized session when serving the file.

However, if you insist to go this way, there's a workaround. Let's lay out a sample directory structure:

```
/path/to/web/document/root
├── manual
│   └── .htaccess
│   └── file1.pdf  # protected
│   └── file2.pdf  # protected
│   └── file3.epub # protected
├── documentation.php
├── listing.php    # protected
└── .htaccess
```

You want the files in the `manual/` directory to be protected and only access when users are logged-in. So, you put the directives below in your `manual/.htaccess` file:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ /documentation.php [R]
# Your own rewrite rule has a syntax error and 
# causes a 500 internal error
```

This will **redirect** all requests to the `documentation.php` file in the parent directory. Drop the `R` flag if you don't need an external redirect.

As you said, now the problem is that any request to the files inside `manual/` is getting redirected to the documentation file.

The workaround is to check the `HTTP_REFERER` header and make sure that the request is coming from the `listing.php` file.

```bsh
RewriteEngine on

# Feel free to change example.com with your own domain    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com/listing.php$
RewriteRule ^ /documentation.php [R]
```

This way any direct request to `manual/file2.pdf` will result in a redirection to `documentation.php`, but if a user clicks on a link in `listing.php` she can access the file without any problem.

If you need to make the referer condition more generic, see this article:
[Referrer Checking with .htaccess](http://tltech.com/info/referrer-htaccess/)

Be warned [that a user can easily **spoof** the `HTTP_REFERER` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104768/65732) and thus access the files without the need to be logged-in. The only real bullet-proof way to implement this is what I said at the beginning of this post.

You might also want to protect the `manual/` directory using basic http auth. But this way, users need to enter another username/password combination to access that folder.

Comment: then how could i access files if place them outside the root?

Comment: PHP can access the files outside of your document root. See [How to serve big files through PHP](http://teddy.fr/2007/11/28/how-serve-big-files-through-php/) to get the idea. You also have other workarounds, see: [Best strategy to protect downloadable files -php/mysql Apache2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5377241/65732) and [Serving Large Protected Files in PHP/Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232547/65732).